# Is my Bayes Theorem answer correct?

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability

Just wanted to confirm that my understanding of Bayes is correct:

People brought 200 chocolate chip cookies and 100 oatmeal raisin cookies. Total = 300 cookies.

You also know that 150 (out of 200) of the chocolate chip cookies have M&Ms, and
25 (out of 100) of the oatmeal raisin cookies have M&Ms.

Now if you see a cookie in front of you and it has M&M's.
Using Bayes Theorem, what is the probability of it being oatmeal raisin?

---

My thought process:

A = Has M&Ms

B = Oatmeal Rasin

P(B|A) = ( P(A|B)P(B) )/ P(A)

P(oatmeal rasin | Has M&Ms)
= P(Has M&Ms | oatmeal rasin) * P(oatmeal rasin) / P(Has M&Ms)

P(Has M&Ms) = (150+25)/300 = 175/300

P(oatmeal rasin) = 100/300 = 1/3

P(Has M&Ms | oatmeal rasin) = 25/100 = 1/4

=(1/4)*(1/3) / (175/300) = **0.142, 14.2% chance the cookie is oatmeal rasin given it has M&Ms?**

Comment: Your answer looks correct to me. Would you like to see a simulation of this problem in R code? Perhaps, you, and other people, might find it helpful to visualize this type of problem in a computer program and see how the simulation agrees with the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. And that would be great if you have the time!

Comment: Because you don't need Bayes' Theorem to find the answer, computing it directly from the joint probability distribution will help you check your work.